# On some Android phones (Android 13), my Flutter app crashes on startup with: no static method "Lkotlin/UByteArray;.get-impl([BI)B"

Tags: flutter, crash

Good day all,

I'm currently running into an issue where my Flutter app is using an external SDK (artifacts only source code is unavailable) The app runs 100% fine wth no issues on all Android emulators from Android SDK version 31 all the way to SDK version 34. On some real Android Samsung devices with Android 13 installed, the app crashes on startup with the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lkotlin/UByteArray;.get-impl([BI)B"
```

The strange thing is it only happens on some phones and on others it works just fine. All phones are Samsungs with Android 13 that we've tested it with. There doesn't seems to be a difference in supported Android API levels between these phones and they all have a recent update of Android 13 installed yet on some the app crashes on startup and not on others.

When I went through the tombstones on the devices it crashes with, I can see that it crashes on the OnCreate method from the external SDK I'm using.
Unfortunately I don't have the source code for the SDK and will probably never be able to obtain it. Is there any advice anyone have for me to do something that I can do to make it work?